# Codeigneiter return controller

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

How do I switch between controls in codeigneiter 4?

```
public function index()
    {
        $db = \Config\Database::connect();
        $query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM musste');
        $results = $query->getResultArray();
        $viewData = array("results" => $results);
        return view('index', $viewData);
    }
```

For example, what can I do to work this function again.I get an error when I use return view again.

```
public function login()
    {
      return view('index');
    }
```

is failing here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `login()` function try to:

`return $this->index();`

instead of

`return view('index');`

Comment: Which is because your index method is Not a View. It's a Method that returns a view. So the above will work.

Comment: yes it worked. So how can I redirect to another controller.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the route()->to() method, that will do what you want.